# Magento last insert id in middle of transaction

Tags: magento, transactions, last-insert-id

I am using transactions in Magento.
I need to use primeryKey of first insert query to all my subsequent queries.

```
    $model1->setfield1()
           ->setField2();
    $transaction->addObject($model1);
    $connection    = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $lastInsertId  = $connection->fetchOne('SELECT last_insert_id()'); // return 0
    $model2->setfield3($lastInsertId )
    $model3->setfield4($lastInsertId )
    $transaction->addObject($model2);
    $transaction->addObject($model3);

    $transaction-Save();
    $lastInsertId2  = $connection->fetchOne('SELECT last_insert_id()'); // returns correct result
```

how to get last inserted id before saving the transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess PDO (which magento uses) can't get last_inserted_id while transaction isn't commited yet. I guess you should either try plain sql like [there](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,115807,115812#msg-115812) or try use nested transactions.

Comment: How can I use nested transactions in Magento?

Answer (score 2):

Tyy this:
$lastInsertId = $connection->lastInsertId();

Comment: Hi Sudhir, Calling it before saving the transaction returns 0, just like my code was returning, calling it after saving the transactin return correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the case with transactions, but I usually do it like this:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$list = Mage::getModel('myextension/list')->setData($data);
$list->setUserId($userId)
    ->setCreatedTime(now());

try
{
 $list->save();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
 return $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}

$last_insert_id = $list->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento transaction does not change data in the DB until you call `save()` method:

```
$transaction->addObject($model1);
...
$transaction->save();
```

`addObject()` just adds new object to the transaction's registry (`\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction::$_objects`). `$model1->save()` method will be called on `$transaction->save()`. No **INSERT** operation is performed before `$transaction->save()` call.